# Sony Handycam HDR-CX210 Creates JPGs Frequently While Shooting Video

Tags: camera, video-recording, photos, memory

I have a Sony Handycam HDR-CX210, and I shot 10 minutes of footage continuously tonight. When I imported it into my PC, the Handycam's memory also included 80-ish JPG images that were stills from the video.  Is that a feature I turned on accidentally?  Or is that standard (to create periodic thumbnails or something)?  I don't need those stills, and they take up memory (1.5 MB each x 80 = 120 MB).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only function which does this is called *Smile Shutter*. Please have a look at the [official manual](https://docs.sony.com/release/HDR-CX190_CX200_CX210_PJ200_guide_EN.pdf) at page 110.

You can disable it under:

```
Menu > Camera/Mic > Face > Smile Shutter
```